# How to extract matching values from a column in a dataframe when semicolons are present in R?

Tags: r, subset, text-mining

I have a large dataframe of published articles for which I would like to extract all articles relating to a few authors specified in a separate list. The authors in the dataframe are grouped together in one column separated by a ; . Not all authors need to match, I would like to extract any article which has one author matched to the list. An example is below.

```
Title<-c("A", "B", "C")

AU<-c("Mark; John; Paul", "Simone; Lily; Poppy", "Sarah; Luke")

df<-cbind(Title, AU)

authors<-as.character(c("Mark", "John", "Luke"))

df[sapply(strsplit((as.character(df$AU)), "; "), function(x) any(authors %in% x)),]
```

I would expect to return;

```
Title   AU
  A      Mark; John                          
  C      Sarah; Luke
```

However with my large dataframe this command does not work to return all AU, it only returns rows which have a single AU not multiple ones.

Here is a dput from my larger dataframe of 5 rows

```
structure(list(AU = c("FOOKES PG;DEARMAN WR;FRANKLIN JA", "SIMS DG;DOWNHAM MAPS;MCQUILLIN J;GARDNER PS", 
"TURNER BR", "BUTLER J;MARSH H;GOODARZI F", "OVERTON M"), TI = c("SOME ENGINEERING ASPECTS OF ROCK WEATHERING WITH FIELD EXAMPLES FROM DARTMOOR AND ELSEWHERE", 
"RESPIRATORY SYNCYTIAL VIRUS INFECTION IN NORTH-EAST ENGLAND", 
"TECTONIC AND CLIMATIC CONTROLS ON CONTINENTAL DEPOSITIONAL FACIES IN THE KAROO BASIN OF NORTHERN NATAL, SOUTH AFRICA", 
"WORLD COALS: GENESIS OF THE WORLD'S MAJOR COALFIELDS IN RELATION TO PLATE TECTONICS", 
"WEATHER AND AGRICULTURAL CHANGE IN ENGLAND, 1660-1739"), SO = c("QUARTERLY JOURNAL OF ENGINEERING GEOLOGY", 
"BRITISH MEDICAL JOURNAL", "SEDIMENTARY GEOLOGY", "FUEL", "AGRICULTURAL HISTORY"
), JI = c("Q. J. ENG. GEOL.", "BRIT. MED. J.", "SEDIMENT. GEOL.", 
"FUEL", "AGRICULTURAL HISTORY")
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first row of the result be `Mark; John; Paul` ? Or do you want to filter out names are not in the authors list?

Comment: @Aziz, My guess was that they want all authors since `Sarah; Luke` has an author not named in `authors`. It's a good question though.

Answer (score 0):

in Base-R you can access it like so

```
df[sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Names, "; "), function(x) any(authors %in% x)),]

    Title            Names
1     A Mark; John; Paul
3     C      Sarah; Luke
```

Comment: Ah, sorry there was a problem with my question. I should have converted df to a dataframe as that is what I am working on with my large data set. The code provided only returns a row showing the matching Name when used on a dataframe and I would like to return all rows with all data where any name is matching. Any advice please? I could provide more code if that helps?

Comment: Not sure i completely understand, But I've edited my code that it works with factors. If it does not help you could edit your question to include a `dput(head(df,10))`  of your data.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `str_extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(Names = str_extract_all(Names, str_c(authors, collapse="|"))) %>% 
   filter(lengths(Names) > 0)
#  Title      Names
#1     A Mark, John
#2     C       Luke
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Title, Names)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by subsetting on those `Names` that match the pattern specified in the first argument to the function `grepl`:

```
df[grepl(paste0(authors, collapse = "|"), df[,2]),]
     Title Names             
[1,] "A"   "Mark; John; Paul"
[2,] "C"   "Sarah; Luke"
```

Comment: @Sim0ne Thanks for this positive feedback. Please consider accepting the answer (by clicking the tick mark in the left upper corner) if it solved your problem and please consider upvoting any answers including this one if they provided useful information.